# One type definition to cover properties of primitive and generic types without unioning

Tags: angularjs, generics, typescript, promise

This is the pattern that requires me to define two types that I would like to refactor/consolidate:

```
...
.then((result1: any) => {
    let promises = {
       one: $q.when(val1),
       two: $q.when(val2)
    };
    return $q.all(promises);
})
.then((resolvedPromises: any) => {
    // use
    resolvedPromises.one...
    resolvedPromises.two
});
```

I would like to define type of `promises` and `resolvedPromises` but as they are type related I would like to define a single type (likely generic) instead of defining two types with similar definition.

So instead of:

```
public interface ResultingType {
    [id: string]: any,
    one: Something1,
    two: Something1
}

public interface PromisingType {
    [id: string]: ng.IPromise<any>,
    one: ng.IPromise<Something1>,
    two: ng.IPromise<Something2>
}
```

The problem is that from the usual generic type perspective we provide the inner-most type to be *injected* into, but in my case I need to somehow define the *outer* type either being `ng.IPromise<>` or nothing actually.

I also don't want to end up with a single type that would allow both types:

```
public interface ConsolidatedType {
    [id: string]: any | ng.IPromise<any>,
    one: Something1 | ng.IPromise<Something1>,
    two: Something2 | ng.IPromise<Something2>
}
```

This would allow for mixing and matching in invalid places. So that's a no-go. Is there any other way to actually have a single type without code repetition that only wraps types into promises?

Comment: I'm not sure I get your code. If `promises` is of type `ResultingType` then aren't the `one` and `two` should be promises? As you assign them with `$q.when(...)`? Also, why do you have defined those interfaces as indexable (that is, why do you have `[id: string]: any` there?)

Comment: 1. **Why indexing?** To satisfy the `$q.all` call, because it's defined as `all(promises: { [id: string]: IPromise<any>; }): IPromise<{ [id: string]: any; }>` so basically I just define two additional predefined properties that fall into the same type definition.

Comment: 2. **Should `one` and `two` be promises in result?** No. Because we should provide promises when creating a deferred but when they get resolved we get their resolved values instead of resolved promises. See `$q.all` definition in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
interface BaseType<T, S> {
    [id: string]: T;
    one: S;
    two: S;
}
```

And then:

```
...
.then((result1: any) => {
    let promises = {
       one: $q.when(val1),
       two: $q.when(val2)
    } as BaseType<ng.IPromise<any>, ng.IPromise<Something1>>;
    return $q.all(promises);
})
.then((resolvedPromises: BaseType<any, Something1>) => {
    // use
    resolvedPromises.one...
    resolvedPromises.two
});
```

You can also create "shortcuts":

```
interface PromiseType extends BaseType<ng.IPromise<any>, ng.IPromise<Something1>> {}

interface ValueType extends BaseType<any, Something1> {}
```

And then:

```
...
.then((result1: any) => {
    let promises = {
       one: $q.when(val1),
       two: $q.when(val2)
    } as PromiseType;
    return $q.all(promises);
})
.then((resolvedPromises: ValueType) => {
    // use
    resolvedPromises.one...
    resolvedPromises.two
});
```

Comment: This is a viable solution although not very nice, as my predefined properties aren't of the same type. If we have two of them we end up with a generic type with three generic subtypes, if more it's always N = number of exrea properties, then we have a generic type with N+1 sub types.